# awk appears to be miscalculating dates

Tags: date, logging, awk

I have a log file where each line begins with a date; here is an example line:

```
26/06/2020 00:00:01  Executing daily job...
```

I am using the following awk command:

```
awk -v d="$(date -d "1 month ago" "+%d/%m/%Y")" '$1 $2 > d' log > temp-log
```

The result is supposed to be log entries in the last month but I only get the last day.

Comment: If you're comparing dates as strings, you want a format like 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' for them to be ordered and compared correctly.

Comment: This might help: `awk '{sep="/"; split($1,array,sep); $1=array[3] sep array[2] sep array[1]; print}' log`

Answer (score 0):

So, putting it all together, we get this solution:

```
cat logfile | awk -v startdate="$(date -d "1 month ago" "+%Y/%m/%d")"  '
{sep="/"; split($1,array,sep); $1=array[3] sep array[2] sep array[1]; 
if ($1 > startdate) print}'
```